# force Magento to use APC cache

Tags: magento, caching, apc

I just installed Magento Commerce on my vps hosting account and am getting bad performance. To help speed up the site, I installed the APC cache but am having trouble getting it to work.

I followed all the steps and seemed to get APC installed. No problems. When I check APC.php, it only shows 1 hit and 1 miss to the cache, which can't be right... Making me think APC isn't active or being used.

I tried to ensure Magento uses APC by adding the following to /var/www/app/etc/local.xml.

```
<cache>
                <backend>apc</backend>
                <prefix>alphanumeric</prefix>
        </cache>
```

Any help is much appreciated. check it here http://www.bindaaslo.com/apc.php
screenshot - http://bindaaslo.com/Screenshot%20from%202014-01-27%2010:50:12.png

Comment: Did you clear the config cache after making this change?

Comment: i was clear cache but there is same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using a unique string other than "alphanumeric". That way if you are sharing APC with other users or applications, your cache will be differentiated.

In your local.xml, the context should be like this:

```
  ...
  <session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
  <cache>
    <backend>apc</backend>
    <prefix>YourUniqueString</prefix>
  </cache>
</global>
```

Also, clear your contents from your var/cache/ folder after changing local.xml and restart your server if necessary.